# Java LocalDateTime remove the milliseconds from UTC timezone

Tags: java, truncate, localdatetime

I am trying to truncate milliseconds from a `UTC` time zone.

I have the code below where I am able to remove milliseconds but I still get the `Z` at the end.

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime eventDateTime=now.minus(4, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

System.out.println("====Event date Time before truncate===");
System.out.println(eventDateTime);
      
System.out.println("====Event date Time after truncate===");
System.out.println(eventDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

This outputs the following:

> ====Event date Time **before** truncate===
>
> **`2021-03-09T20:46:24.081Z`**
>
> ====Event date Time after truncate===
>
> **`2021-03-09T20:46:24Z`**

Comment: Call [`OffsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to get the date/time value without a time zone.

Comment: The `Z` just indicates that it's UTC. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` if you want a particular output format.

Comment: Please give more context why you think you want to do this, and I believe we can guide you better. While I can see that users may want not to see fraction of second and UTC offset, they most often want the time in their own time zone rather than UTC, and they perfer a more localized date and time format. So for what purpose then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Z` is the timezone information. You can convert the `OffsetDateTime` instance to a `LocalDateTime` like this:

```
eventDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toLocalDateTime()
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

To represent a moment in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class rather than `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant
    .now()                        // Returns a `Instant` representing the current moment including a fractional second.
    .truncatedTo( 
        ChronoUnit.SECONDS        // Granularity of what you want chopped off. In this case, we lop off any fractional second.
    )                             // Returns another `Instant` object. Per immutable objects, a new object is instantiated rather than altering ("mutating") the original.
    .minus(                       // Go backwards on the timeline.
        Duration.ofMinutes( 4 )   // Amount of time to go backwards.
    )                             // Returns another `Instant` object. 
    .toString()                   // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, with `Z` on the end meaning an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the UTC temporal prime meridian.
```

## Zulu time

The `Z` at the end represents vital information: the date-time represents a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. This letter is defined as part of the standard formats in ISO 8601. The letter is pronounced “Zulu” per aviation/military tradition.

If you do not care about offset or time zone in your problem domain, then you are using the wrong type.

The types `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` all represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. All three involve an offset or time zone.

## `LocalDateTime`

If you want only a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of an offset/zone, then use `LocalDateTime`. No `Z` will appear in text representing the value of a `LocalDateTime` because no offset is involved.

Just be aware that a `LocalDateTime` object is inherently ambiguous, and does not represent a moment. In other words, calling `LocalDateTime.now` is almost never the right thing to do. But if you insist:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I was blindly doing stuff like trimming out the trailing ````z```` and all ;)

Answer (score 2):

There can be two ways:

1. Preferred way: Use `DateTimeFormatter`
2. Use [`OffsetDateTime#toLocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--): The problem with this approach is that the output string is automatically truncated to minutes if the seconds part is zero.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithoutSecFraction = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithSecFraction = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        OffsetDateTime eventDateTime = now.minusMinutes(4);

        System.out.println("====Event date Time before truncate===");
        System.out.println(eventDateTime);
        System.out.println(eventDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
        System.out.println(dtfWithSecFraction.format(eventDateTime));

        System.out.println("====Event date Time after truncate===");
        System.out.println(eventDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
        System.out.println(eventDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toLocalDateTime());
        System.out.println(dtfWithoutSecFraction.format(eventDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
====Event date Time before truncate===
2021-03-09T21:17:17.589016Z
2021-03-09T21:17:17.589016
2021-03-09T21:17:17.589016
====Event date Time after truncate===
2021-03-09T21:17:17Z
2021-03-09T21:17:17
2021-03-09T21:17:17
```

Note that `Z` stands for `Zulu` which specifies date-time in UTC (i.e. a timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

The following table gives you an overview of *java.time* types:

[image]

As you can see, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` etc. carry timezone information and you can get just the date-time part using the techniques mentioned in the solution above.

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.